# How to change the value in dynamic rows of the table without affecting previous one?

Tags: javascript

In dynamic table when i enter the debit column of rows,the credit column should be display as "0".
When i enter the credit column of rows and debit column shows "0".
 My problem is if i enter in the debit column ,the credit column shows "0".if i enter in the next row of credit column,the previous row debit column also shows "0" value.Only existing rows only display the value "0".My code affecting previous row also.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.Debit').on('change input',function() {

                var amount = 0;
               var hh2 = 0;
               $('.tb3 > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
               var pamt = $(this).find('.Debit').val();

                 $(this).find('.Credit').val(0);


         hh2 += parseFloat(pamt);


                });

                $('#TotD').val(hh2);
        });



        $('.Credit').on('change input',function() {

                var amount = 0;

                 var hh2 = 0;
                $('.tb3 > tbody  > tr').each(function() {



$(this).find('.Debit').val(0);
                    var pamt = $(this).find('.Credit').val();



                    hh2 += parseFloat(pamt);

                });
                 $('#TotC').val(hh2);
        });

    });

</script>



 <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive pre-scrollable">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-xxs tb3" id="tb3">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Account Name</th>
                                    <th>Debit</th>
                                    <th>Credit</th>
                                    <th>Particulars</th>
                                    <th>Cost Center</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr >
                                    <td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove3'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>

                                    <td><select style="width:120px" class="form-control" name="name[]" id="name">
                <option></option>
                <?php foreach ($PName as $row ): ?> 
                <option value="<?=$row['name']?>"><?=$row['name']?></option> 
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                        </select></td>

                                    <td ><input style="width:80px" type="text"  class="form-control input-xs Debit" name = "Debit[]"   > </td>


                                    <td><input style="width:80px" type="text"  class="form-control input-xs Credit"   name="Credit[]"></td>

                                    <td><input style="width:100px" type="text" id=""  class="form-control input-xs" value="" name="Parti[]"></td>


<td><input style="width:80px" type="text" id="Cost"  class="form-control input-xs" value="" name="Cost[]"></td>



                                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore3" title="Add More Person"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></td>



                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 clearfix">

                        <div class="col-xs-6">

                            <div class="form-group "><br>
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Total:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">

                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Amount" id="TotD" class="form-control grandto" name="TotD" value="0" >

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">

                            <div class="form-group "><br>

                                <div class="col-md-4">

                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Amount" id="TotC" class="form-control grandto" name="TotC" value="0" >

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        </div>
```

Comment: what is #TotC, #TotD - is this ID for that credit and debit cell?
It will be useful if you share html code too

Comment: No that is not id for row,that is sum of all rows of credit and debit is calculated and display in totC and totd text box

Comment: can you please add html code for this so that we can understand the problem easily?

Comment: i edited the code sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you set all credit or debit value to 0 by loop `each` ! So move your setting 0 value outside of `each`

```
$('.Debit').on('change input',function() {    
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.Credit').val(0); // move from each loop
  ...remaining code

$('.Credit').on('change input',function() {    
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.Debit').val(0); // move from each loop
  ...remaining code
```

Comment: @Tom did you remove this line inside each() $(this).find('.Credit').val(0)
Then the above change by David will work i think so

Comment: @IllllIllSanthoshKumarIllllI Right ! @Tom so I comment out move your set code from `each` scope

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like-

```
     $('.Debit').on('change input', function() {
        var debit = 0;
        var credit = 0;
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.Credit').val(0);
        $('.tb3 > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
            debit += parseFloat($(this).find('.Debit').val());
            credit += parseFloat($(this).find('.Credit').val());
        });
        $('#TotD').val(debit);
        $('#TotC').val(credit);
    });

    $('.Credit').on('change input', function() {
        var debit = 0;
        var credit = 0;
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.Debit').val(0);
        $('.tb3 > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
            debit += parseFloat($(this).find('.Debit').val());
            credit += parseFloat($(this).find('.Credit').val());
        });
        $('#TotD').val(debit);
        $('#TotC').val(credit);
    });
```

Note: Since when you input on debit field credit value becomes 0 for that row, your total calculations including Debit and Credit should also reflect not just only one( credit or Debit). I also removed amount varibale as it was not being used.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a fiddle where this is working?

I also see that you are using classes to target your elements. This will affect all elements that have this class.

Also remember that find() searches through all the descendants of your element executing the code on all of them, like here:

```
var pamt = $(this).find('.Credit').val();
```

Comment: i can't understand

Comment: @Cre3z is correct, the find function will return all elements of that class. Within the onchange event, `this` should refer to the element being changed, so I would suggest using getting its parent element (the tr) and then using that to find the other Debit / Credit box.

Comment: That only i am using what i have to change,i can't understand

Comment: @Tom remove this line inside each() $(this).find('.Credit').val(0);

Comment: Ok then how i shows credit column as a zero while entering debit column and vice versa